# Linq Pivot from SQL Query

Tags: c#, sql, linq, pivot

I have problem with Linq, the code used to be processed in sql via stored procedure, but right now it supposed to be on code via linq, here's my database schema

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/644f7/2)

what I want is , from this data

| orderNo | Type | serial |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | BN | BN 1 |
| 1 | BE | BE 1 |
| 2 | BN | BN 2 |
| 2 | BE | BE 2 |
| 3 | BN | BN 3 |
| 3 | BE | BE 3 |

to be like this :

| orderNo | be | bn |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | BE 1 | BN 1 |
| 2 | BE 2 | BN 3 |
| 3 | BE 2 | BN 3 |

found one question and solution [Source 1 - Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11103940/how-to-do-a-pivot-in-linq) , when I tried   to my code, I got an issue with SelectMany

here's what I've tried

```
var results = data_tech.GroupBy(l => l.serial).SelectMany( g => 
                     new 
                     { 
                         Metadata = g.Key, 
                         data = g 
                     });


 var pivoted = new List<PivotedEntity>();

foreach(var item in results)
{
    pivoted.Add( 
        new PivotedEntity
        {
            Order= item.orderNo,
            BE= item.data.Where(x => x.Name == "BE")
                        .FirstOrDefault().value,
            BN= item.data.Where(x => x.Name == "BN")
                         .FirstOrDefault().value,
        });
}
```

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Comment: Change it to `GroupBy(l => l.OrderNo)` and add `BE = g.FirstOrDefault(x=> x.Type == "BE" && x.OrderNo == g.Key).Serial` to the anonymous object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply achieve this by changing the group by element *serial* to *OrderNo*. Let me give you an example,

```
        var list = new List<Order>() {
            new Order { orderNo = 1, Type = "BN", Serial = "BN 1" },
            new Order { orderNo = 1, Type = "BE", Serial = "BE 1" },
            new Order { orderNo = 2, Type = "BN", Serial = "BN 2" },
            new Order { orderNo = 2, Type = "BE", Serial = "BE 2" },
            new Order { orderNo = 3, Type = "BN", Serial = "BE 3" } ,
            new Order { orderNo = 3, Type = "BE", Serial = "BN 3" } };

            var results = list.GroupBy(l => l.orderNo).Select(g =>
                new
                {
                    Metadata = g.Key,
                    data = g
                });

            var pivoted = new List<PivotedEntity>();

            foreach (var item in results)
            {
                pivoted.Add(
                    new PivotedEntity
                    {
                        Order = item.Metadata,
                        BE = item.data.Where(x => x.Type == "BE")
                                    .FirstOrDefault().Serial,
                        BN = item.data.Where(x => x.Type == "BN")
                                     .FirstOrDefault().Serial,
                    });
            }
```

This will give you some output like this image. [image: Quick Watch output window]

Edit: Output PivotedEntity class =>

```
internal class PivotedEntity
    {
        public int Order { get; set; }
        public string BE { get; set; }
        public string BN { get; set; }
    }
```